# Toggle a class by a button from header component that affect main app component by Angular 6+

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass

My app by Angular simply starts with **index.html**:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I would like it to be switched between Dark/Light by toggling between `<body>` and `<body class="dark-mode">` with below styles:

```
body abcxyz {
  color: #fff
}

body.dark-mode abcxyz {
  color: #a2b3c4
}
```

Next is **app.component.html** with Header - Main - Footer as usual:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The **header.component.html** has a toggle button:

```
<button (click)="onClickDarkMode()">Dark Mode</button>
```

We need a variable and a function like this to work, I put them in **header.component.ts**:

```
isDarkMode = false;
onClickDarkMode() {
  this.isDarkMode = !this.isDarkMode;
}
```

This idea seems simple to implement, but the click event seems like it fires to nothing with any of these lines added to the `<body>`:

```
<body [class.dark-mode]="isDarkMode">
```

or

```
<body [ngClass]="{'dark-mode': isDarkMode}">
```

or

```
<body [ngClass]="isDarkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''">
```

Further more, with the idea of "Dark/Light", is this the best way to implement by toggling class inside the `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close! I would highly recommend using a service so that you can effectively share state between components.

Basically what it looks like is a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeService {

    /**
     * Variable to hold our setting.
     */
    public darkMode: boolean;

    /**
     * Enable/disable "dark mode" by flipping the bit.
     */
    public toggle(): void {

        this.darkMode = !this.darkMode;

    }

}
```

and the component:

```
<div class="wrapper" [class.dark-mode]="themeService.darkMode">

    <div class="text">

        Dark Mode Enabled? {{ themeService.darkMode ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}

    </div>

    <div class="button">

        Parent Component

        <button (click)="themeService.toggle()">Toggle!</button>

    </div>

    <app-child></app-child>

</div>
```

You will use dependency injection to "expose" the `ThemeService` like so:

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './theme.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent {

    /**
     * Inject the theme service which will be called by our button (click).
     *
     * @param {ThemeService} themeService instance.
     */
    public constructor(public themeService: ThemeService) {

    }

}
```

By using a service you can not only share state but also wire up more properties like font-size, etc from a central location.

I have a brief tutorial explaining how to wire things up at https://matthewdavis.io/theme-service accompanied by the project repo https://github.com/mateothegreat/ng-byexamples-theme-service.

Hope this helps you along your journey. Feel free to ask questions!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!
Could you help me clarify this property declaration in 2 constructors above: `public themeService: ThemeService` in app.component and child.component, why public here, are the two the same or they are different? Can I declare differently like `public themeServiceHeader: ThemeService` in the Header meanwhile in App with `public themeServiceApp: ThemeService`? Last one: what is the use of `public constructor() { }` because I can see `constructor() { }` also works, no need public for these constructors?

Comment: They are public so you can access it from the template. I just make it a habit to use scoping with all of my methods :)

Comment: I used a `theme` service, it works fine for all components by toggling class 'dark-mode' in app.component.html, until I found out that `<ng-template let-modal>` is under the `<body>`, of couse these modals don't work. 

I turned to another solution: I tried to inject `DOCUMENT` and `Renderer2` into the header and it works fine. But I see now the `theme` service is deprecated, so I put `Renderer2` to the `theme` service, and it refused to work! 

Could you help me to retain the `theme` service, and still be able to apply the theme to all the components (and these modals as well)?

Answer (score 1):

Components and their variables are scoped in Angular. This means, that a public variable in your component like `isDarkMode` is only known by the component itself and the template. There's no global representation of that variable.

While this works:

```
<app-header>
  <div [ngClass]="{'dark-mode': isDarkMode}">
</app-header>
```

This won't:

```
<body [ngClass]="{'dark-mode': isDarkMode}"></body>
```

---

What you can do is to set the class of the `body`-element in your component. But keep in mind that you should avoid manipulating the DOM directly and that your application should be platform agnostic.

That's why you should use Angular's dependency injection:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.less']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  darkMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleDarkMode() {
    this.darkMode = !this.darkMode;

    if (this.darkMode) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'dark-mode');
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'dark-mode');
    } 
  }
}
```

Now only the `HeaderComponent` can change the class. You should make this more versatile by using a service, so that you can do things like:

- change the mode from any place in your application
- through events make it possible for other components to be informed when the mode is changed

Comment: I used a `theme` service, it works fine for all components by toggling class 'dark-mode' in app.component.html, until I found out that `<ng-template let-modal>` is under the `<body>`, of couse these modals don't work. 

I turned to your solution, tried to inject `DOCUMENT` and `Renderer2` into the header and it works fine. But I see now the `theme` service is deprecated, so I put `Renderer2` to the `theme` service, and it refused to work! 

Could you help me to retain the `theme` service, and still be able to apply the theme to all the components (and these modals as well)?