# Theme service that affects all components and modals <ng-template let-modal> in Angular 6+

Tags: html, angular, service, sass, themes

- According to the post [Toggle a class by a button from header component that affect main app component by Angular 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123292/toggle-a-class-by-a-button-from-header-component-that-affect-main-app-component/59123692#59123692)

  I created a `theme` service, it works fine for all components by toggling class `'dark-mode'` in `app.component.html`, until I found out that all of my modals `<ng-template let-modal>` are under the `<body>`, of course these modals don't work.
- So I turned to another solution from this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/59123790/6630524](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59123790/6630524)

  I tried to inject `DOCUMENT` and `Renderer2` into the `header` component and it works fine. But I see now the `theme` service is deprecated, so I put `Renderer2` to the `theme` service (not in `header` component anymore), and it refused to work!

Could you help me to retain the `theme` service, and still be able to apply the theme to all the components (and these modals as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out no one answered for quite some time, so I decided to dig into the solution myself, see below FYI.

First, still keep using the `theme` service by putting `Renderer2` into the `theme.service.ts` (previously set locally in `header` component):

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ThemeService {
      public isDarkMode: boolean;
      private renderer: Renderer2;

      constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
        rendererFactory: RendererFactory2
      ) {    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
      }

      public toggleDarkMode() {
        this.isDarkMode = !this.isDarkMode;

        if (this.isDarkMode) {
          this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'dark-mode');
        } else {
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'dark-mode');
        } 
      }
    }
```

Second, you need to set a public variable in a constructor, here I choose the constructor of `header.component.ts`:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
      /*
      * Inject the theme service which will be called by our button (click).
      * @param {ThemeService} themeService instance.
      */
      constructor(public themeService: ThemeService) {}

      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Then put a button in the `header.component.html` to toggle your themes (Note: You can put the button anywhere in your project, along with the public variable defined in the corresponding `abc.component.ts`)

```
<button (click)="themeService.toggleDarkMode()"><i class="fa fa-moon"></i></button>
```

Now the public `toggleDarkMode` function is fired anytime the button clicked, then the modals and other components will reflect the change when theme service get updated by your defined `dark-mode` style, for example:

```
#lucky.dark-mode {
    color: #a2b9c8;
    background-color: #01263f!important;
}
```

And you might need this applied to all the `<body>` in `index.html`:

```
<body id="lucky">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Good luck and happy coding!